# Scraping in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am newbie in python and I am working on a project where given an input category page e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_algorithms

Scrape all the contents listed under A-Z (not subcategories but the actual wiki pages). So, basically, go into Adative heap sort and save the content on disk.
I am looking into scrapy http://scrapy.org/ 
but havent been able to figure out the template I need to put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to read **Scrapy docs** here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Based on your use case, I would also recommend you to read about **Spider arguments** here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments.

Once done, follow these steps in your shell:

1. Create Scrapy project

   > scrapy startproject wikipedia
   >
   > cd wikipedia
2. Create your first Spider

   > scrapy genspider categories wikipedia.org
3. Create your first Item (WikipediaItem). Edit **wikipedia/items.py**, delete everything and add this code:

   ```
   #coding:utf-8
   import scrapy

   class WikipediaItem(scrapy.Item):
       category_name = scrapy.Field()
       category_url = scrapy.Field()
       letter_name = scrapy.Field()
   ```
4. Edit **categories** Spider, which is located in **wikipedia/spiders/categories.py**, delete everything and add this code:

   ```
   #coding:utf-8
   import scrapy
   from wikipedia.items import WikipediaItem

   class CategoriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       name = "categories"
       allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]

       def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
           super(CategoriesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           if category is not None:
               self.start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:%s' % category]

       def parse(self, response):
           sel = response.xpath
           item = WikipediaItem()

           categories_letters = sel('//div[@id="mw-pages"]/div/div/div[@class="mw-category-group"]')
           for letter in categories_letters:
               letter_name = ''.join(letter.xpath('.//h3/text()').extract()).replace(u'\xa0', u'')
               for category in letter.xpath('.//ul/li/a'):
                   category_name = ''.join(category.xpath('.//@title').extract())
                   category_url = ''.join(category.xpath('.//@href').extract())
                   item['category_name'] = category_name
                   item['category_url'] = category_url
                   item['letter_name'] = letter_name
                   yield item
   ```
5. Finally, schedule the crawl with a category of your choice. In this case I've used **Sorting_algorithms** category:

   > scrapy crawl categories -a category=Sorting_algorithms -o results.json -t json
6. I'll let your shell show you the results. This is just a part of what you want to achieve, you can continue reading the docs, and asking if you have any doubts. Hope this helps.